# Cocoa pod issue: ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F...'

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

So I've looked at some of the answers that seem to be about similar issues, and I have been unable to solve the problem.  I just upgraded to XCode 8.0, but I didn't solve this same issue before I upgraded, possibly a significant error in judgement, but here I am.  I cannot find the paths in question in the settings of XCode.  I honestly don't know where they came from.  I've just been following the basic directions on how to install these two cocoa pods, and I am so close to success.  Any help that you can give me would be fantastic.  Thanks for your consideration.

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/seanzlatnik/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FluctuateApp-dwftgojouclofedrueeenyfijogv/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ABCustomUINavigationController'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/seanzlatnik/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FluctuateApp-dwftgojouclofedrueeenyfijogv/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Charts'
ld: framework not found ABCustomUINavigationController
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Sincerely, 
Sean

Comment: Which version of cocoapods do you have? use pod --version in terminal

Comment: I'm using version 1.0.1.